# How to query Cassandra table directly in Spark 2.1?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

In spark 1.6, we could use `cassandraSqlContext` to query directly against a cassandra table, like so:

```
cassandraSqlContext.sql("select * from keyspace.tableName")
```

Is there any such feature in spark 2.1?

I know spark 2.1 doesn't have cassandra sql context, instead it has a spark session. If i do `spark.sql("select * from keyspace.tableName")` it throws error about unresolved relation or tablename doesn't exist.

However I can register the cassandra table to a dataframe and then query the dataframe.

Is that the only way to query the cassandra table in 2.1?

```
  def registerMetaDataDF(adminKeySpace: String, tableName:String): DataFrame = {
    val df = sparkSession.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map("table" -> tableName, "keyspace" -> adminKeySpace))
      .load()
    df
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the Spark version, accessing Cassandra from a Spark application requires [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) package:

> This library lets you expose Cassandra tables as Spark RDDs, write Spark RDDs to Cassandra tables, and execute arbitrary CQL queries in your Spark applications.

So, your question really boils down to the following:

> Is `cassandraSqlContext` gone in Spark 2.1?

My limited experience tells me that [CassandraConnector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#connecting-manually-to-cassandra) is something you may want to look at:

> If you ever need to manually connect to Cassandra in order to issue some CQL statements, this driver offers a handy CassandraConnector class which can be initialized from the SparkConf object and provides access to the Cluster and Session objects. CassandraConnector instances are serializable and therefore can be safely used in lambdas passed to Spark transformations as seen in the examples above.

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md, they are kinda doing the same thing as me for reading the cassandra table.

Comment: I did not say that there are other ways to access Cassandra table. I said that executing CQL is through CassandraConnector.